# How can I draw a rectangle over a widget without stealing its events?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

I'm trying to implement a custom docking solution using a `Gtk.DrawingArea` placed upon a `Gtk.Overlay`, but when I attempt to show the `Gtk.DrawingArea` during a widget's `drag_motion` event it triggers the `drag_leave` event. The problem here is that I'm using the drag_leave event to hide the overlay, which means that I'm just toggling between visibility states as the cursor is moving. How can I prevent the overlay from triggering the bottom widget's `drag_leave` event after it has been made visible?

Also, is there a more efficient way to approach docking? Should I be using Gtk.Window instead of Gtk.DrawingArea? What is the best way to draw a simple rectangle over a region and have it move when an item is dragged?

- I've tried using a Gtk.EventBox instead of a Gtk.DrawingArea
- I've tried using a Gtk.Window with Gtk.WindowType.POPUP instead of a Gtk.Overlay
- I've tried using GDL but I would prefer to create my own widgets using vala
- I've tried calling `gtk_overlay_set_overlay_pass_through`
- I've tried calling `gdk_window_set_pass_through`

```
using Gtk;
using Gdk;

public const Gtk.TargetEntry[] targets = {
    { "INTEGER", 0, 0 },
};

void main (string[] args) {
    Gtk.init (ref args);

    var window = new Gtk.Window ();
    window.set_default_size (400, 400);
    window.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;

    var container = new Gtk.Overlay ();

    var box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);

    container.add (box);
    var box_overlay = new Gtk.DrawingArea ();
    box_overlay.realize.connect (() => {
        box_overlay.get_window ().set_pass_through (true);
        box_overlay.hide ();
    });

    container.add_overlay (box_overlay);
    container.set_overlay_pass_through (box_overlay, true);

    var dest_drag_widget = new Gtk.Button ();
    dest_drag_widget.vexpand = true;
    var src_drag_widget = new Gtk.Button ();
    src_drag_widget.vexpand = true;

    Gtk.drag_source_set (src_drag_widget, Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, targets, Gdk.DragAction.COPY);
    Gtk.drag_dest_set (dest_drag_widget, Gtk.DestDefaults.MOTION, targets, Gdk.DragAction.COPY);

    dest_drag_widget.drag_motion.connect (() => {
        if (!box_overlay.visible) {
            print ("show\n");
            box_overlay.show ();
        }
        return false;
    });
    dest_drag_widget.drag_leave.connect (() => {
        if (box_overlay.visible) {
            print ("hide\n");
            box_overlay.hide ();
        }
    });

    box.add (dest_drag_widget);
    box.add (src_drag_widget);

    window.add (container);
    window.show_all ();

    Gtk.main ();
}
```

1. Run the above with `valac --pkg gtk+-3.0`
2. Drag bottom button to top and move it around
3. Notice "show" and "hide" being printed many times.

I expect "show" and "hide" to only be printed once.

Edit:

The overall effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to how the Atom editor positions its panes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I came up with the following solution:

1. Hide the overlay by default
2. Make the overlay a drag destination alongside the original destination
3. When user drags over original destination, show the overlay and tell it to handle the drag_motion by passing the original destination's rectangle
4. Hide the overlay when cursor leaves rectangle

This probably has some gotchas that I've yet to consider but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right answer might depend on exactly what kind of effect you're looking for.

You could render the source widget to a pixbuf and call `Gtk.drag_source_set_icon_pixbuf()`[1](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.drag_source_set_icon_pixbuf.html) to set that to be dragged around.

You could try unparenting the source widget from its existing container and add re-adding it to the overlay, then use absolute positioning to move the whole widget.

Or it might just be easier to use the existing dock widgets in [libdazzle](https://valadoc.org/libdazzle-1.0/Dazzle.html).

Apologies for lack of concrete suggestions!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I should note that I'm using the rectangle to denote the placement of the source widget; i.e. if my cursor is to the inner left of the destination it draws a rectangle with half of its width as an overlay. Would using libdazzle help me achieve something like that?

Comment: Ah okay, dazzle might not help too much since it's a suite of concrete widgets -- its dock works in a specific way, take it or leave it. You could look at its source though to see how that handles the dragging, but it's probably written in C. Two other things to try would be to a) just keep the DrawingArea visible all the time, or b) place the Overlay and the DrawingArea over the dest widget only, i.e. in its own container.